# Function arguments, return all records from database table

Tags: php

I have a script that loops through and returns all records in the database table, code below.

PHP:

```
for($i=0;$i<$group_layer_row;$i++){
$my_layer_string="MyMap_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result ($rs_group_layer, $i, 0),"UTF-8","SJIS")."_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result ($rs_group_layer, $i, 1),"UTF-8","SJIS");
echo "var ".$my_layer_string.";\n";
}
```

What I am trying to do is turn this into an argument. Somewhat like this(this is an example, please don’t judge).

PHP:

```
function getLayers(){
$my_layer_string="MyMap_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result ($rs_group_layer, $i, 0),"UTF-8","SJIS")."_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result ($rs_group_layer, $i, 1),"UTF-8","SJIS");
$layers="var ".$my_layer_string.";\n";
echo $layers;
}
for($i=0;$i<$group_layer_row;$i++){
getLayers();
}
```

Any help on this would be very appreciated.

For reference I am including the sql query

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM m_group_layer WHERE group_id=\"".$_SESSION["group_id"]."\" ORDER BY display_order";
$rs_group_layer= mssql_query ($sql, $con);
$group_layer_row =mssql_num_rows($rs_group_layer);
```

EDIT: This is almost the exact same loop just with different output.

```
for($i=0;$i<$group_layer_row;$i++){
$my_layer_string="MyMap_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result ($rs_group_layer, $i, 0),"UTF-8","SJIS")."_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result ($rs_group_layer, $i, 1),"UTF-8","SJIS");
echo "".$my_layer_string." = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( \"".$my_layer_string."\",\"http://192.0.0.0/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/mapserver/data/toyama/toyama_mymap.map&service=WMS&SRS=EPSG:2449&VERSION=1.1.1&format=image/PNG&layers=".$my_layer_string."\", {'layers': '".$my_layer_string."'},  {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: false,opacity:0.5,alpha:true});
map.addLayer(".$my_layer_string.");\n";
}
```

Comment: $rs_group_layer and $i need to be passed as arguments of your getLayers function, e.g. function getLayers($rs_group_layer, $i){...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is a prime candidate for creating an object. As for making a function out of it, I think it's significantly cleaner to process the db resultset in a for loop. I don't see much benefit to creating a function (as passing the db result back and forth to a function inside a loop is very inefficient). Perhaps you might clarify your reasoning for wanting a function or what you are looking to accomplish?

BUT, if you really wanted to make a function out of it it would pretty much look how you outlined it ...

```
function getLayer($result_set, $row) {
  $str  = "MyMap_" . mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result($result_set, $i, 0),"UTF-8","SJIS")
  $str .= "_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result($result_set, $i, 1),"UTF-8","SJIS");
  return "var MyMap_$str;\n";
}

// $con = ...
$sql = "SELECT * FROM m_group_layer WHERE group_id=\"".$_SESSION["group_id"]."\" ORDER BY display_order";
$result = mssql_query ($sql, $con);
$row_count = mssql_num_rows($result);

for($i=0; $i<$row_count; $i++){
  echo getLayer($result, $i);
}
```

**UPDATE -- CLASS EXAMPLE**

Okay, hopefully this doesn't scare you away. Everyone was afraid of OOP at some point. The important thing is to keep working at it and eventually you'll be like, 'OMG I <3 OOP LIKE GAGA LOVES HER LITTLE MONSTERS!!!'

I tried to document as much as possible. There's only so much you can explain without teaching a semester course :)  How to use it is at the bottom of the code.

```
<?php

/**
 * Retrieves layers from the db and provides methods for outputting
 */
class LayerMaker
{
  /**
   * Our MSSQL database connection
   * @var MSSQL connection resource
   */
  protected $db_conn;

  /**
   * Our array of records from the DB
   * @var array
   */
  protected $records;

  /**
   * Constructor function
   * 
   * Called when you first instantiate the object. If you specify
   * the db_conn, it will go ahead and retrieve the records as
   * soon as the object is created.
   * 
   * @param MSSQL connection resource $db_conn
   * 
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct($db_conn=NULL)
  {
    if ($db_conn) {
      $this->set_db_conn($db_conn);
      $this->records = $this->query_db();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Setter function for protected $db_conn property
   * 
   * You could just as easily create a method in the object
   * to create the db connection, but for testing reasons that
   * you likely don't care about it's better to inject the
   * db connection into our object using a setter function like this.
   * 
   * @param MSSQL link identifier $db_conn
   */
  public function set_db_conn($db_conn)
  {
    $this->db_conn = $db_conn
  }

  /**
   * How we get the records from the database into our object's $results property
   * 
   * @return MSSQL record set on success or FALSE if no db connection is set
   */
  protected function query_db()
  {
    // make sure we've set a database connection to use
    // query the db and return the results
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM m_group_layer WHERE group_id="' .
      $_SESSION["group_id"] . '" ORDER BY display_order';
    return mssql_query($sql, $this->db_conn);
  }

  /**
   * A function to get a count of the rows in our result set
   * 
   * @return int Rows in the result property
   */
  public function count_result_rows()
  {
    if ($this->records) {
      return mssql_num_rows($this->records);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  /**
   * Wrapper for mb_convert_encoding function
   * 
   * @return string
   */
  protected function layer_builder($row)
  {
    $str0  = mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result($this->records, $row, 0),"UTF-8","SJIS")
    $str1 = mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result($this->records, $row, 1),"UTF-8","SJIS");

    return "var MyMap_$str0_$str1";
  }

  /**
   * Finally, build our layers!
   * 
   * @param int $row Result set row number
   * 
   * @return mixed Layer string if $row specified or Array of all layer strings
   *               if no specific row requested
   */
  public function get_layers($row=NULL)
  {
    if ($row) {
      // if we want one specific row ...
      return $this->layer_builder($row);
    } else {
      // otherwise, give us back an array of all the rows
      $layers = array();
      for($i=0; $i<$this->count_result_rows(); $i++){
        $layers[] = $this->layer_builder($i
      }
      return $layers;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Getter function for protected $records property
   *
   * Useful because you might want access to the resultset
   * outside of the object context.
   * 
   * @return array MSSQL record set
   */
  public function get_records()
  {
    return $this->records;
  }
}


// Now this is how you could use it
$conn = (however you retrieve a db connection);
$layer_obj = new LayerMaker($conn);
$layers = $layer_obj->get_layers();

print_r($layers);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Yes a class would actually be the best as I am pretty much using a copy of this loop a few times just with a slightly different output. So the best would be to be able to just instantiate a class. Unfortunately I am terrified of OO. I’ve added another example of this loop. If you could help with a class I would be much obliged. Thanks again.

Comment: sure ... i would've done it first but i wanted to make sure it'd be useful before i spent the time :) forthcoming ...

Comment: please note that i didn't test the actual code ... tried to make sure everything was legit but there may be a stray comma or single-quote somewhere.

Comment: No problem. There were a few fixes, but works like a charm (Sorry can't give you any rep... gotta wait for 15 for myself before I can start give'in them)

Comment: haha no worries. i just know how much of a struggle it was to understand oop at first and now it's second nature and i love it, so i try to evangelize people when possible. glad i could help